# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()

Tags: spring, tomcat7

When i'm launching the Tomcat server it  gives the following error:

Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start

The errors obtained in the console are:

> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:222)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:83)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext.getSessionCookieConfig()Ljavax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig;
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1374)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1346)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more

It will be grateful if someone could share the solution.
Thanks!

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name />
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <description>generated-persistence-filter</description>
        <filter-name>hrbFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>hrb</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <description>generated-sitemesh-filter</description>
        <filter-name>Sitemesh Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hrbFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Sitemesh Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <description>generated-servlet</description>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>generated-servlet</description>
        <servlet-name>PrimeFaces Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>generated-servlet</description>
        <servlet-name>hr_demo Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:hr_demo-web-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <description>generated-resources-servlet</description>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PrimeFaces Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: what is your Java version ?

Comment: Please show your `web.xml`.

Comment: please find above the web.xml. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a classpath issue. Make sure there isn't a servlet.jar in the classpath other than the one already included in Tomcat_HOME/lib

Comment: there is no servlet.jar in the folder lib but there is servlet.api.jar.

Answer (score 0):

Write localhost:yourportnumber on your web browser. Is your Tomcat server working? If Tomcat server is not working on your web browser, you could not load Tomcat server correctly, try again and click startup.bat under the C:\tomcat\bin.

If Tomcat server is working correctly, put Tomcat folder on C:/Tomcat. And show classpath (Tomcat installation directory) on your IDE.